# orderByChild not ordering my list of numbers

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of goals with a match, but it does not order nothing by goals, what I want is to order all the the statics fetched by qty , so I want to show in my RecyclerView the users that have more qty first and then the other ones

[image]

So, what I have tried is the followin

```
    mDatabase.child("statics").child(snapshot.getKey()).orderByChild("qty").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 long qty = 0;            
for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren(){
                Model model = snapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                String name = model.getName();
                long qty = qty + model.getQty();
                model.setName(name);
                model.setQty(qty);
                arrayList.add(model);    
            }

            mAdapter = new Adapter(this,arrayList,R.layout.recycler_row);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But this is not ordering by the child qty when my recyclerview is shown, either way is ordering it in reverse so I could flip the recyclerview, instead is showin for example this list

```
2

6

2
```

Where `snapshot.getKey()` is a list of userID returned by other call, so I fetch all the users from that node statics

Comment: What is the value of `snapshot.getKey()`? And how did you get it? Also show the minimal code for `onDataChange` with which you can reproduce the problem, as right now it's hard to be certain where the problem is.

Comment: snapshot.getKey() is only the userID key returned from another call, so with that I know where to enter inside statics - userID

Comment: I will update the question

Comment: Edited Frank, take a look at it, one of the biggest issues using Firebase realtime database at the momment is querying and ordering results

Comment: If the key is pointing to one of the nodes under `/statics` in the image you shared, then you should be getting only one result. Each user node has only one child.

Comment: One of my biggest challenges are ordering requests from Firebase realtime database, as my client need those values ordered, I cant switch to firestore at this moment, is anyone having or solved this issue ?

Comment: Hi frank , I just loop with the foreach for each user inside statics and get the qty of each one of them

Comment: since .child(snapshot.getKey()) is calling this query for each user, that for is for multiple keys inside that child, but now the results are like my question 2  6 2

Comment: When you run the code you shared on the data you shared, there is at most one child node matching the query. If you're calling this code multiple times, show how you call it. Without seeing the [minimal, complete code and data that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is is going to be hard to help. In general for problems like this, it is best to start anew to reproduce the minimal problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for hints on how and why to do that.

Comment: frank , and what do you think about ordering the arraylist that is filled with the firebase data ? then pass that array sorted into the adapter and show it sorted with my recyclerview ? is that a good approach or it should be better to fetch the data ordered from Firebase ?

Comment: solved it doing a sort of the array :)